# Can't connect to Google Cloud server via HTTP or HTTPS

Tags: windows-server-2012, http, https, google-compute-engine

This must be a very simple beginner's question. I created an instance on the Google Cloud Platform, with a Windows 2012 Server on it. I can RDP into it, but I can't connect to it via HTTP or HTTPS (by typing the IP address in the browser address bar). I'm getting an error:

> This Site can't be reached
>   xx.xxx.xxx.xxx took too long to respond

I did check the boxes "Enable HTTP" and "Enable HTTPS" when I created the instance.

Any recommendations or ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you've configured the network-based firewall properly, but you haven't mentioned anything about configuring the host firewall.

Comment: I solved the issue by opening another port on the Network Firewall. Apparently, the authentication function required port 4244. Once I allowed that on the network firewall, the server become accessible.

Comment: Please post that below as a proper answer and then accept the answer.

Comment: I thought I did?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by opening another port on the Network Firewall. Apparently, the authentication function required port 4244. Once I allowed that on the network firewall, the server become accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Google cloud doesn't automatically create the dns zone records during server creation like other hosting services. I added a DNS record for my could server's external ip address in the 'Cloud DNS' tab to resolve the above issue.